# non-disabled checkbox being targeted by the :read-only pseudo element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to understand a problem that has been bugging me for a while, now.

I am wondering why checkboxes would be targeted by the pseudo element `:read-only`, even when not having the `disabled` attribute.

See the snippet below :

```css
input:read-write + label {
  background-color: green;
}

input:read-only + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- an active ( not disabled ) checkbox -->
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">the checkbox</label>

<br /> 
<br />

<!-- a disabled text -->
<input type="text" disabled id="text"/>
<label for="text">the text</label>

<br /> 
<br />

<!-- an active ( not disabled ) text -->
<input type="text" id="text-active"/>
<label for="text-active">another text</label>
```

As you can see, both the checkbox and the first text input are targeted by the `input:read-only`, even though only the first text input has the `disabled` attribute.

I've done some research and came across [this article on the subject](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/read-only/#:%7E:text=%3Aread%2Donly%20is%20a%20CSS,and%20that%20are%20not%20disabled.) which stated :

> :read-only is a CSS pseudo-class selector that matches any element that does not match the :read-write selector.

Naturally I followed with a research on the `:read-write` pseudo selector and ended up on the [mdn web docs page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:read-write), which stated :

> The :read-write CSS pseudo-class represents an element (such as input or textarea) that is editable by the user.

I feel like, since I can toggle the value of the checkbox, it should be considered "editable by the user" ?

I've made some test in some browser, Both Firefox ( 90.0 ) and Brave ( v. 1.27.109 Chromium: 92.0.4515.115 ) seams to have the problem.

I also tested in an old version of chrome ( Version 89.0.4389.90 ) and the behavior was not the same. Both element were unaffected by the `:read-only` pseudo-element, and the second text field was affected by the `read-write` pseudo element, even with the `disabled` attribute. Weird.

Maybe I'm missing something obvious ?

Comment: There is similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62754768/why-is-the-pseudo-class-read-only-not-working-for-a-disabled-element

Comment: @ishaba thanks for your suggestion, however, I'm not sure this question is relevant on my case, since i'm working with checkbox and they are not.

Comment: There is no difference between any input and checkbox from that point of perspective

Comment: @ishaba there clearly is, the behavior is working fine on input text, while it is not working properly with checkboxes.

Comment: Oh sorry my bad. I see now what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found why this behavior is occuring.

According to the [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#selector-read-only)

> The :read-only pseudo-class must match all other HTML elements.

Here, the *all other HTML elements* refer to the html elements on which the `:read-write` property does not apply.

On the same page, we can see what define an html element that is *`:read-write`-able*.

> The :read-write pseudo-class must match any element falling into one of the following categories, which for the purposes of Selectors are thus considered user-alterable:
>
> - input elements to which the readonly attribute applies, and that are mutable (i.e. that do not have the readonly attribute specified and that are not disabled)
> - textarea elements that do not have a readonly attribute, and that are not disabled
> - elements that are editing hosts or editable and are neither input elements nor textarea elements

The relevent part, here, is *input elements to which the readonly attribute applies*. If we check the [HTML standard page for checkboxes](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#checkbox-state-(type=checkbox)), we can see that the `readonly` attribute, indeed, **does not** apply.

> The following content attributes must not be specified and do not apply to the element: accept, alt, autocomplete, dirname, formaction, formenctype, formmethod, formnovalidate, formtarget, height, list, max, maxlength, min, minlength, multiple, pattern, placeholder, **readonly**, size, src, step, and width.

Which makes the checkbox falls into the categories of html elements on which the `:read-write` property cannot be applied. Hense the behavior of the original question's snippet.

While this does not explain how to bypass the behavior ( see [Aditya's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68592955/5784924) ), It explains why it is occuring, which was the part I was originaly interessed in.

As an aditional note, I'm still not sure as why it the background-color was not working of the `:read-only` element in Chrome 89.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```css
input:read-write + label {
  background-color: green;
}

input:disabled + label {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox">the checkbox</label>

<br /> 
<br />

<input type="text" disabled id="text"/>
<label for="text">the text</label>

<br /> 
<br />

<input type="text" id="text-active"/>
<label for="text-active">another text</label>
```

Instead of using `read-only` you can use `disabled` in your css

According to your question you need to change the style of a disabled input but as you're using `:read-only` this means the input which is set to readonly is changed!

```css
input:read-only { background: #121212; color: #fff; }
input:disabled { background: #555; color: #00aeff; }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="ReadOnly" readonly><br>
<input type="text" value="Disabled" disabled><br>
<input type="text" value="ReadOnly & Disabled" readonly disabled>
```

Check this [WebPage](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_read-only) Read more about Readonlys

Conclusion? Well there's a Difference between Read-Only and Disabled inputs.

Comment: While that could "fix" my problem, I'm not looking for a fix, really. I'm trying to understand why a certain  behaviour is happening.

Comment: Checkout i've updated the answer, and yea Don't forget to give that tick man, Stay Safe!